# Can a .gitlab-ci.yml be shared between repositories?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

If I have multiple repositories in Gitlab under the same Group and if each one has a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file which is identical, is there a way to centralize the `.gitlab-ci.yml` code, such that it's shared between these repositories?

With the setup I explained above, if I want to change something in this `.gitlab-ci.yml`, I need to do it for each repo separately.

P.S. If not the full file, is it possible to share parts of the code (or centralize parts of the CI code)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `include` reserved word in your gitlab-ci.yml file to call out to another projects gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
include:
  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    file: '/templates/.gitlab-ci-template.yml'
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#include
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#single-string-or-array-of-multiple-values